# Can't assign to PS1 on OS X bash

Tags: bash, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to set up `PS1` so it displays the branch name on git:

`user.name:some/repo (master) $`

However, nothing I do seems to work. Even when I just try assigning to `PS1` directly, it doesn't work:

```
user.name:~ $ echo $PS1
\u:\w $
user.name:~ $ PS1='oh yeah'
user.name:~ $ echo $PS1
\u:\w $
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I not have permissions to set this var? Do I have a syntax error?

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.

I also tried:

```
user.name:~ $ echo $PS1
\u:\w $
user.name:~ $ export PS1='oh yeah'
user.name:~ $ echo $PS1
\u:\w $
```

For reference:

```
user.name:~ $ $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**Apparently `PS1` is readonly. Interesting.**

```
user.name:~ $ readonly PS1
-bash: PS1: readonly variable
```

How do I make it not readonly?

Comment: You're in a restricted shell where you're not allowed to change it? Or the value is set readonly?

Comment: Are you sure you are running BASH (I agree, it sure looks that way but we're in the twilight zone here)? What is the output of `$SHELL --version`?

Comment: Try `readonly` in the shell to see if PS1 is readonly.

Comment: Type just `readonly` on its own to list read-only variables.  Typing `readonly PS1` will set it read-only, which is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: How do I unset it?

Comment: There's a Solution on StackOverflow :: [Appending Git Branch Name to Bash $PS1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816790/append-gits-branch-name-to-command-prompt) ...

Comment: I am having the same issue on Yosemite, and none of the "solutions" solved this issue.

Comment: OK, I found my issue. I was setting $PS1 in a different place in my .bash_profile. If future reader run into the same issue, you might want to double check your bash_profile first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check you rc files to make sure PS1 isn't being defined readonly in them.

try the following:

```
user@server$ PS1='oh yeah :'
oh yeah :readonly PS1
oh yeah :PS1='different PS1 :'
bash: PS1: readonly variable
oh yeah :bash
user@server$ PS1='something else '
something else
```

try

```
grep -E 'PS1=' ~/.bashrc <other rc files>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
export PS1='oh yeah'
```

[Source](http://www.nattl.at/2009/04/howto-set-shell-environment-variables-on-mac-osx-105/)

Comment: Yep - OP updated

Comment: Are you administrator user? Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Surprising, it should work and it's for sure not a permission issue.

Did you try double quotes `export PS1="oh yeah"` instead of `export PS1='oh yeah'` ?